# asp.net link: How to optionally execute code behind in the current page instead of loading the new page

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-routing

On one of my main menu links, I need to check a condition and eventually not load the page but display a toast message via code behind. Something like a router condition in Angular (?). Is that possible? (I don't want to reroute from the loaded page back to the main page if the condition is false, as it just looks ugly.)

```
<div class="nav-link-container">
    <a runat="server" id="_feedbackLink">Feedback</a>
</div>
```

(The link's href is set in code behind.)

Comment: Is JS possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

not sure this really is a routing issue.

Replace the link with a button, or say link button. Then you can have a plain jane code behind stub. If conditions are met, then just navigate to the new page.

So, you could have say this:

```
<li id="m8" runat="server"><a id="A1" runat="server" 
     href="~/MyPortal/Approved" 
     title="View your projects">View Approved</a>
```

and it now becomes this:

```
<li id="myproofcheck" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" >
     <asp:LinkButton ID="btnProofMainSite" ClientIDMode="Static" 
         Text="My Proofs " runat="server"
         OnClick="btnProofMainSite_Click"
         >View Approved</asp:LinkButton>
</li>
```

So, now it just a button code behind.

You could have

```
if (some condition ok) 
   response.Redirecto("~/myPortal/ViewProjects")
else
   MyToastm(Me.Page, "myproofcheck", "No Projects", "No Projects waiting", 6000)
```

My toast function is just server side routine that sets up a client side jQuery.toast message.

So user would see this if I don't navigate:

[image]

So, don't use a href link - but drop in a plane jane button (or link button) and style it the same as the menu. Now user clicks, check what ever condition you like, and then

Navigate with server code (Response.Redirect)

or

call your routine to display the toast message and don't navigate.

I not done this for a mvc page, but for asp.net webforms, it does work fine. So most of the standard menu is hefs with a link, but some of the bootstrap menu items can be a simple server side button + code.